# Python vector plot missing labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, label

I am trying to plot vectors and give each vector a unique label.
The code below shows my reasoning. The issue is that only one label is added.
I have also tried label=labs[:] in the plt.quiver() command, without success.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")
text1_occurences = [2,1]
text2_occurences = [1,2]
vectors = np.array([text1_occurences,text2_occurences])
origin = np.array([[0, 0],[0,0]])
labs = ["text1","text2"]


plt.quiver(*origin,vectors[:,0],vectors[:,1],color=["r","g"],angles="xy",scale_units="xy",scale=1,label=labs)
plt.xlim(0,2.5)
plt.ylim(0,2.5)
plt.legend()
plt.legend(["text1","text2"], loc=1)
plt.legend(["text2"], loc=2)
plt.xlabel("Goodbye")
plt.ylabel("Hello")
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: Current plot, one label missing]

As you can see, one label (green, text 2) is missing.

Comment: Have you considered using `plt.quiverkey`?

Comment: @BigBen I have not seen `plt.quiverkey` before. I tried to implement it but did not fully understand how to do so. If you have the time, I would appreciate it if you could show an example. If not, then thats fine. In the end, I ended up adding the labels with `plt.text`. This worked fine for this time, but for future use I'm sure theres a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, I don't believe `quiver` supports a separate label for each arrow.

You could use [`quiverkey`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiverkey.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20quiverkey#matplotlib.pyplot.quiverkey) to add a key, though this approach would be similar to just using `plt.text`.

```
q = plt.quiver(*origin,vectors[:,0],vectors[:,1],color=["r","g"],angles="xy",
               scale_units="xy",scale=1)

plt.quiverkey(q, .1, .9, .2, labs[0], color='g', labelpos='E')
plt.quiverkey(q, .1, .83, .2, labs[1], color='r', labelpos='E')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean about it being similar to `plt.text`. Thank you for taking the time to show this.

Comment: @Aleks - yes. My guess is that you'd have to have a separate `plt.quiver` call for each arrow if you wanted to use a unique label per arrow. Seems like the above or `plt.text` is appropriate for your use case (hopefully). Then again, maybe someone will post another answer and prove me wrong, since I'm definitely not a matplotlib expert.